# How can I debug this Google AppScript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a spreadsheet form based on this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2X-fArILPA

My form has many more inputs than the example video AND I wish for the output to be displayed in rows, instead of columns. This makes it easier to copy/paste the data into other formats, like emails.

I got almost all the scripts to work perfectly EXCEPT this line:

```
 dataSheet.getRange(dataSheet.getLastColumn() +1,1,1,6).setValues(values);
  CLEAR();
```

I am aware that +1,1,1,6 refers to rows and columns, but I cannot seem to get it to work. In other words, I don't know which numbers to add in which order. The output spreadsheet should start adding data in Cell B1. There are 36 Rows.

When I add a console.log, the script runs fine, but nothing shows up in my Output sheet tab when I hit the button to "Submit."

Instead, I get this error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null
Details: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null
```

Below is the full script within the curly brackets:

```
function SUBMISSIONS() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var formSheet = ss.getSheetByName("CREWING-INPUT")  
var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("OUTPUT");
var values = [[ formSheet.getRange("D8").getValue(), 
              formSheet.getRange("D9").getValue(),
              formSheet.getRange("D10").getValue(),
              formSheet.getRange("D11").getValue(),
              formSheet.getRange("D12").getValue(),

              formSheet.getRange("C13").getValue(),
              formSheet.getRange("C14").getValue(),
              formSheet.getRange("C15").getValue(),

              formSheet.getRange("E13").getValue(),
              formSheet.getRange("E14").getValue(),
              formSheet.getRange("E15").getValue(),
              formSheet.getRange("E16").getValue(),

              formSheet.getRange("D16").getValue(),
              formSheet.getRange("D19").getValue(),

              formSheet.getRange("B18").getValue(),

              formSheet.getRange("E21").getValue(),
              formSheet.getRange("E22").getValue(),
              formSheet.getRange("E23").getValue(),
              formSheet.getRange("E24").getValue(),
              formSheet.getRange("E25").getValue(),
              formSheet.getRange("E26").getValue(),
              formSheet.getRange("E27").getValue(),

              formSheet.getRange("F21").getValue(),
              formSheet.getRange("F22").getValue(),
              formSheet.getRange("F23").getValue(),
              formSheet.getRange("F24").getValue(),
              formSheet.getRange("F25").getValue(),
              formSheet.getRange("F26").getValue(),
              formSheet.getRange("F27").getValue(),
              formSheet.getRange("F28").getValue(),
              formSheet.getRange("F29").getValue(),
              formSheet.getRange("F30").getValue(),
              formSheet.getRange("F31").getValue(),
              formSheet.getRange("F32").getValue(),

              formSheet.getRange("D33").getValue(),
              formSheet.getRange("D34").getValue(),
              formSheet.getRange("D35").getValue(),
              formSheet.getRange("D36").getValue(),

              formSheet.getRange("E34").getValue(),

              formSheet.getRange("D37").getValue(),

              formSheet.getRange("E37").getValue(),

              formSheet.getRange("C38").getValue()]];
dataSheet.getRange(dataSheet.getLastColumn()+1).setValues(values);
CLEAR();
}

console.log(SUBMISSIONS)
```

---

This is the code that I ended up using in the end, which worked:

```
function SUBMISSIONS() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var formSheet = ss.getSheetByName("CREWING-INPUT")  // The name 
of the spreadsheet tab for the form
var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("OUTPUT"); // The name of the
spreadsheet tab for the collection of submissions
var sheetValues = [[new Date().toLocaleString()], // The order of 
this list DOES MATTER and will be reflected in the output rows
                 [formSheet.getRange("D8").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("D9").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("D10").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("D11").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("D12").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("C13").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("C14").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("C15").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("E13").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("E14").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("E15").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("D16").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("E16").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("B18").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("D19").getValue()],  
                 [formSheet.getRange("E21").getValue()],  
                 [formSheet.getRange("E22").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("E23").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("E24").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("E25").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("E26").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("E27").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("F21").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("F22").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("F23").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("F24").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("F25").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("F26").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("F27").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("F28").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("F29").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("F30").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("F31").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("F32").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("D33").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("D34").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("D35").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("D36").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("E34").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("D37").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("E37").getValue()],
                 [formSheet.getRange("C38").getValue()]];
dataSheet.getRange(1, dataSheet.getLastColumn()+1, 
sheetValues.length, 
sheetValues[0].length).setValues(sheetValues);

}
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity, is there a reason you're taking this approach, versus just using Google Forms? Forms has the ability to insert all responses into a Sheet on submission into a row.

Comment: @NEWAZA Thanks for asking. Yes, there is a huge reason why I'm improving on the Google Forms Template by using a Spreadsheet instead. Google Forms is far too cumbersome and space-consuming when it comes to inputting multiple dates and times that are supposed to correspond with each other.  I started with Google Forms as a "better than nothing" option and now we are upgrading.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### This works

```
function SUBMISSIONS() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0")  
var osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var vs = [[ sh.getRange("D8").getValue(), 
              sh.getRange("D9").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("D10").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("D11").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("D12").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("C13").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("C14").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("C15").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("E13").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("E14").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("E15").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("E16").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("D16").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("D19").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("B18").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("E21").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("E22").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("E23").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("E24").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("E25").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("E26").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("E27").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("F21").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("F22").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("F23").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("F24").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("F25").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("F26").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("F27").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("F28").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("F29").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("F30").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("F31").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("F32").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("D33").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("D34").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("D35").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("D36").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("E34").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("D37").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("E37").getValue(),
              sh.getRange("C38").getValue()]];
osh.getRange(1,osh.getLastColumn()+1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

#### All in one column:

```
function SUBMISSIONS() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const rgl = sh.getRangeList(["D8", "D9", "D10", "D11", "D12", "C13", "C14", "C15", "E13", "E14", "E15", "E16", "D16", "D19", "B18", "E21", "E22", "E23", "E24", "E25", "E26", "E27", "F21", "F22", "F23", "F24", "F25", "F26", "F27", "F28", "F29", "F30", "F31", "F32", "D33", "D34", "D35", "D36", "E34", "D37", "E37", "C38"]);
  var osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var vs = rgl.getRanges().map(r => [r.getValue()])
  osh.getRange(1, osh.getLastColumn() + 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

Comment: This mostly works! The only issue, is that it displays the results into 1 row of Columns instead of 36 Rows (starting on B1). Is there any way to flip it? Thank you!!! :)

Comment: That's the way you have it written

Comment: There now it is all in one column

Comment: I suppose I should start a new thread to transpose the columns/rows (in the output - not in the code itself). Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is usually better to ask the question that you wish answered upfront.